# Invert boolean in embedded code block

Tags: c#, asp.net

I control visibility of my controls in a GridView through columns of Boolean type in the DataSource.
In the markup I use embedded code blocks:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelTitle" runat="server" 
           Text = '<%# Bind("Title") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("SQL_Column") %>'/>
```

Is there a way to invert this expression? I want the Textbox TextBoxTitle to be displayed if SQL_Column is false and vice versa.

Something like

```
Visible='<%# Eval(!"SQL_Column") %>'
```

I don't want to do it from Code Behind.

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval returns object; you cannot apply exclamation operator to an object.

Instead, you will need to convert to Boolean value first.

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelTitle" runat="server" 
    Text = '<%# Bind("Title") %>' 
    Visible='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SQL_Column")) %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your not `!` inversion outside of your `Eval()` statement.

```
!(bool)Eval("SQL_Column")
```

The way you have it, `!"..."` means you're trying to apply a not operation to the string itself, which doesn't make sense. Before the `Eval()` the not operation means you're trying to invert the returned value of the evaluation.

Note that you need to explicitly cast the evaluated value from an object to a boolean in order to able to invert it.

Comment: I had tried that too but it says "Operator ! cannot be applied to operand of type object"

Comment: That means your `SQL_Column` is evaluating to an object and you need to convert it to a boolean. I'll update the answer.